# How to serialize form stored in a variable jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, web

```
form = '<form action="javascript: this.preventDefault">'+

    '<input type="hidden" name="term" value="'+term+'" />'+

     '<input type="hidden" name="course" value="'+course+'" />'+

      <input type="hidden" name="seq_no" value="'+seq_no+'" />'+

'</form>';

var url = 'Add_Row.php?edit&',//relative path to PHP processing script

input = form.serialize();
```

Here I am trying to place a form into a variable form after which I want to serialize that form then send it off to be processed.

However I keep getting this error from the browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: form.serialize is not a function

Your help will be much appreciated

Blessings STM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.serialize` is not a function because `form` is just a string, not a jQuery object.  Use:

```
input = $(form).serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your `form` variable is a string. `serialize()` is a jQuery method only available on jQuery objects, therefore you need to convert your `form` variable:

```
var input = $(form).serialize();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jro03xtw/)