# Use JS variables and serialize for AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'd like to have the following code in my AJAX request:

```
function ajax_post( form_info ){
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax_handler.php",
    type: "POST",
       data: {data : form_info},
    });
};
```

I'd like to serialize all of the elements in my clicked event to pass directly to the AJAX function because I'm doing processing on the PHP side. Say I have the following on click function:

```
$('.open-popup').on("click", function() {
    var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var contest_id = $('#contest-id').val();
    var contest_type = $('#contest_type').val();
    //serialize everything to a data_to_pass variable
    ajax_post( data_to_pass );
});
```

How could I serialize the clicked_id, contest_id and contest_type into a single variable to pass to my AJAX processing function as a single string of data?

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize form stored in a variable jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974503/how-to-serialize-form-stored-in-a-variable-jquery)

Comment: @DiniZx These elements aren't in a form so I'm not trying to serialize the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
var data_to_pass = {
   clicked_id: clicked_id,
   contest_id: contest_id,
   contest_type: contest_type
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.open-popup').on("click", function() {
    var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var contest_id = $('#contest-id').val();
    var contest_type = $('#contest_type').val();
    var data_to_pass = {
       clicked_id: clicked_id,
       contest_id: contest_id,
       contest_type: contest_type
    };
    ajax_post( data_to_pass );
});
```

**AJAX:**

```
function ajax_post( form_info ){
    var data = JSON.stringify(form_info);
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax_handler.php",
    type: "POST",
       data: {data : data},
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) for that and append all the required values with [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) function.

Like this,

```
$('.open-popup').on("click", function() {
    var clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var contest_id = $('#contest-id').val();
    var contest_type = $('#contest_type').val();
    //serialize everything to a data_to_pass variable

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append( 'clicked_id', clicked_id);
    fd.append( 'contest_id', contest_id);
    fd.append( 'contest_type', contest_type);

    ajax_post(fd);
});
```

And AJAX function would look something like this,

```
function ajax_post( form_data ){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_handler.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
    });
};
```

And access the data in PHP using `$_POST['clicked_id']` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `ajax` accepts objects as data; it takes care of the serialization for you. So you can simply do

```
ajax_post({
    clicked_id:$(this).attr('id'),
    contest_id:$('#contest-id').val(),
    contest_type: $('#contest_type').val()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so, try using a form element and inputs (it can be hidden fields if it isn't a user submitted form) in your HTML code, and serialize it, so you can transmit the whole 'block of information' at one time with Ajax.

Look at rfunduk's answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425095/submit-form-using-ajax-and-jquery) question.